# share image in cordova social share

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to share an image that is stored on my cell phone to my twitter social network. The problem is that the path of the image appears but not the image. how can I solve that?

```
var text="text";
var image="file:///storage/emulated/0/morphingApp/evolucion_1500930109465.gif";
var link="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nintendo.zara&hl=es";

window.plugins.socialsharing
  .shareViaTwitter(text, "",image,link, 
   function(errormsg){ alert("yo dont have twitter app")});
```

I am using android

Answer (score 0):

Is this for iOs or Android?

See:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

Android also double check manifest and 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html

Answer (score 0):

.shareViaTwitter(text,image,link) this is the correction!